# Not able to take user input when using while loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops, input, while-loop

I have this code bellow which is supposed to take a user input and store it in an array, and I was just wondering why it is not allowing me to input any numbers.

Should the input part be inside the if statement? Also what is the best way to make it work properly?

```
import java.util.*;

public class fun_with_loops {

    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.io.IOException
    {
        int[] numbers = new int[10];
        int numberSize = 0;
        System.out.print("Enter a few numbers please\n");



        while (numbers.length < 10)
        {
            int input = scan.nextInt();
            if (input != 0)
            {
                numbers[numberSize] = input;
                numberSize++;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }

        }

    }  
}
```

Comment: Because your numbers.length will always be 10, it will never be less than 10. You need to use a count variable to take user input 10 times to store in the array.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

The following expression on loop's control is always evaluated as false:

```
while (numbers.length < 10)
```

since array's length is in fact equals 10 as when declared.

**Solution**

In order to program work as expected you have to use `numberSize` variable as control:

```
while (numberSize < 10)
```

since it grows based on number of inputs.

Answer (score 0):

As Am_I_Helpful stated, you are using a while loop on a value that will not change. I am not sure if the use while is needed in this case. Since you want to loop a specific amount of times you might want to use a for loop. If the amount of times will depend on the size of your array, you could still replace the "10" by your array length (numbers.length).

```
for (int i; i< 10; i++)
    {
        int input = scan.nextInt();
        if (input != 0)
        {
            numbers[numberSize] = input;
            numberSize++;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }

    }
```

Hoping it helped!

Dan

a short and sweet summary of when to use each loop:
http://mathbits.com/MathBits/CompSci/looping/whichloop.htm

but of course it always depends of your goal while coding so it's sometimes hard to say which is best if you are not the one coding.

Answer (score 0):

Because the array is initialized to size 10, the length will always be 10.  A counter variable needs to be used.  Here is the code:

```
static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main (String[] args) throws java.io.IOException
{
    int[] numbers = new int[10];        
    System.out.print("Enter a few numbers please\n");


    int count = 0;
    while (count < 10)
    {
        int input = scan.nextInt();
        if (input != 0)
        {
            numbers[count] = input;
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `length` property returns the size of the array, not the number of elements that are present in the array. You need to keep track of number of elements in the array on your own.

```
    for(int eleCount = 0; eleCount < 10; eleCount++) 
    {
        int input = scan.nextInt();
        if (input != 0)
        {
            numbers[eleCount] = input;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }

    }
```